# How to generate the JPA entity Metamodel?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, annotation-processing, metamodel

In the spirit of type safety associated with the [CriteriaQuery](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaQuery.html) JPA 2.0 also has an API to support [Metamodel](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/tutorial/doc/gjiup.html) representation of entities.

Is anyone aware of a fully functional implementation of this API (to generate the Metamodel as opposed to creating the metamodel classes manually)? It would be awesome if someone also knows the steps for setting this up in Eclipse (I assume it's as simple as setting up an annotation processor, but you never know).

EDIT:
Just stumbled across [Hibernate JPA 2 Metamodel Generator](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/jpamodelgen/reference/en-US/html_single/) . But the issue remains since I can't find any download links for the jar.

EDIT 2:
Awhile has passed since I asked this question, but I thought I'd come back and add a link to the [Hibernate JPA Model Generator project on SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hibernate/files/hibernate-jpamodelgen/)

Answer (score 91, accepted):

> It would be awesome if someone also knows the steps for setting this up in Eclipse (I assume it's as simple as setting up an annotation processor, but you never know)

Yes it is. Here are the implementations and instructions for the various JPA 2.0 implementations:

#### EclipseLink

- [`org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.modelgen.CanonicalModelProcessor`](http://wiki.eclipse.org/UserGuide/JPA/Using_the_Canonical_Model_Generator_(ELUG))

#### Hibernate

- `org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor`
- http://in.relation.to/2009/11/09/hibernate-static-metamodel-generator-annotation-processor

#### OpenJPA

- `org.apache.openjpa.persistence.meta.AnnotationProcessor6`
- http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/2.4.1/apache-openjpa/docs/ch13s04.html

#### DataNucleus

- `org.datanucleus.jpa.JPACriteriaProcessor`
- http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_2_1/jpa/jpql_criteria_metamodel.html

---

The latest Hibernate implementation is available at:

- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-jpamodelgen/

An older Hibernate implementation is at:

- http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/org/hibernate/hibernate-jpamodelgen/1.0.0.Final/hibernate-jpamodelgen-1.0.0.Final.jar

Comment: The DataNucleus link is dead.

Comment: Hibernate link is dead too

Answer (score 54):

Please take a look at [jpa-metamodels-with-maven-example](https://github.com/jinahya/jpa-metamodels-with-maven-example).

### Hibernate

- We need `org.hibernate.org:hibernate-jpamodelgen`.
- The processor class is `org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor`.

#### Hibernate as a dependency

```xml
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
      <version>${version.hibernate-jpamodelgen}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

#### Hibernate as a processor

```xml
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>process</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <configuration>
              <compilerArguments>-AaddGeneratedAnnotation=false</compilerArguments> <!-- suppress java.annotation -->
              <processors>
                <processor>org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor</processor>
              </processors>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
            <version>${version.hibernate-jpamodelgen}</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>
```

### OpenJPA

- We need `org.apache.openjpa:openjpa`.
- The processor class is `org.apache.openjpa.persistence.meta.AnnotationProcessor6`.
- OpenJPA seems require additional element `<openjpa.metamodel>true<openjpa.metamodel>`.

#### OpenJPA as a dependency

```xml
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.openjpa</groupId>
      <artifactId>openjpa</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <compilerArgs>
            <arg>-Aopenjpa.metamodel=true</arg>
          </compilerArgs>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

#### OpenJPA as a processor

```xml
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>process</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>process</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <configuration>
              <processors>
                <processor>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.meta.AnnotationProcessor6</processor>
              </processors>
              <optionMap>
                <openjpa.metamodel>true</openjpa.metamodel>
              </optionMap>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.openjpa</groupId>
            <artifactId>openjpa</artifactId>
            <version>${version.openjpa}</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>
```

### EclipseLink

- We need `org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor`.
- The processor class is `org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.modelgen.CanonicalModelProcessor`.
- EclipseLink requires `persistence.xml`.

#### EclipseLink as a dependency

```xml
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
      <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

#### EclipseLink as a processor

```xml
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>process</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <configuration>
              <processors>
                <processor>org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.modelgen.CanonicalModelProcessor</processor>
              </processors>
              <compilerArguments>-Aeclipselink.persistencexml=src/main/resources-${environment.id}/META-INF/persistence.xml</compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor</artifactId>
            <version>${version.eclipselink}</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>
```

### DataNucleus

- We need `org.datanucleus:datanucleus-jpa-query`.
- The processor class is `org.datanucleus.jpa.query.JPACriteriaProcessor`.

#### DataNucleus as a dependency

```xml
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
      <artifactId>datanucleus-jpa-query</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

#### DataNucleus as a processor

```xml
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>process</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>process</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <configuration>
              <processors>
                <processor>org.datanucleus.jpa.query.JPACriteriaProcessor</processor>
              </processors>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
            <artifactId>datanucleus-jpa-query</artifactId>
            <version>${version.datanucleus}</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>
```

Comment: Just to be clear, the generated stuff can be used with eclipselink, even though you use hibernate to generate it, I couldnt generate meta model from netbeans 8 and had to create a maven test project to generate my stuff

Comment: @ymajoros Is it forbidden, in SO, to say `something is recommended` without `IMHO`? I'm not representing on the behalf of anyone else.

Comment: BTW, see Sorter's answer for EclipseLink. This is the configuration I've been using for years and it works perfectly. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037593/how-to-generate-jpa-2-0-metamodel/11245730#answer-24119645

Comment: Isn't this implementation specific I try to use Hibernate generated metamodel with EclipseLink and get NullPointerException

Comment: @ymajoros Still needs a `persistence.xml`, isn't it?

Comment: Can you add instruction for DataNucleus? It'd be appreciated.

Comment: @KarlRichter Check [the project on the github](https://github.com/jinahya/jpa-metamodels-with-maven-example). It already has profiles for working with DataNucleus. Regards.

Comment: The groupId for Hibernate seems to be `org.hibernate` for all Versions before 6.

Comment: Maybe it's worth mentioning that for hibernate-jpamodelgen with Java11 maven-processor-plugin should be at least of version 4.0-rc. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/61305429/5911964

Answer (score 23):

Eclipse's JPA 2.0 support through Dali (which is included in "Eclipse IDE for JEE Developers") has its own metamodel generator integrated with Eclipse.

1. Select your project in the **Package Explorer**
2. Go to **Properties** -> **JPA** dialog
3. Select source folder from **Canonical metamodel (JPA 2.0)** group
4. Click **Apply** button to generate metamodel classes in the selected source folder

[image]

This should work on any JPA provider as the generated classes are standard.

Also see [here](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/development/news/3.2M3/jpa.php).

Comment: Is there some way to kick off the process yourself? This does not reliably produce the metamodel for me

Answer (score 20):

Let's assume our application uses the following `Post`, `PostComment`, `PostDetails`, and `Tag` entities, which form a one-to-many, one-to-one, and many-to-many table relationships:

[image: JPA Criteria Metamodel]

### How to generate the JPA Criteria Metamodel

The `hibernate-jpamodelgen` tool provided by Hibernate ORM can be used to scan the project entities and generate the JPA Criteria Metamodel. All you need to do is add the following `annotationProcessorPath` to the `maven-compiler-plugin` in the Maven `pom.xml` configuration file:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <annotationProcessorPaths>
            <annotationProcessorPath>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
                <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
            </annotationProcessorPath>
        </annotationProcessorPaths>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Now, when the project is compiled, you can see that in the `target` folder, the following Java classes are generated:

```
> tree target/generated-sources/
target/generated-sources/
└── annotations
    └── com
        └── vladmihalcea
            └── book
                └── hpjp
                    └── hibernate
                        ├── forum
                        │   ├── PostComment_.java
                        │   ├── PostDetails_.java
                        │   ├── Post_.java
                        │   └── Tag_.java
```

### Tag entity Metamodel

If the `Tag` entity is mapped as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tag")
public class Tag {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    //Getters and setters omitted for brevity
}
```

The `Tag_` Metamodel class is generated like this:

```
@Generated(value = "org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor")
@StaticMetamodel(Tag.class)
public abstract class Tag_ {

    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Tag, String> name;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Tag, Long> id;

    public static final String NAME = "name";
    public static final String ID = "id";
}
```

The `SingularAttribute` is used for the basic `id` and `name` `Tag` JPA entity attributes.

### Post entity Metamodel

The `Post` entity is mapped like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "post")
public class Post {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String title;

    @OneToMany(
        mappedBy = "post",
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        orphanRemoval = true
    )
    private List<PostComment> comments = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToOne(
        mappedBy = "post",
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY
    )
    @LazyToOne(LazyToOneOption.NO_PROXY)
    private PostDetails details;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name = "post_tag",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "post_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "tag_id")
    )
    private List<Tag> tags = new ArrayList<>();
    
    //Getters and setters omitted for brevity
}
```

The `Post` entity has two basic attributes, `id` and `title`, a one-to-many `comments` collection, a one-to-one `details` association, and a many-to-many `tags` collection.

The `Post_` Metamodel class is generated as follows:

```
@Generated(value = "org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor")
@StaticMetamodel(Post.class)
public abstract class Post_ {

    public static volatile ListAttribute<Post, PostComment> comments;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Post, PostDetails> details;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Post, Long> id;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Post, String> title;
    public static volatile ListAttribute<Post, Tag> tags;

    public static final String COMMENTS = "comments";
    public static final String DETAILS = "details";
    public static final String ID = "id";
    public static final String TITLE = "title";
    public static final String TAGS = "tags";
}
```

The basic `id` and `title` attributes, as well as the one-to-one `details` association, are represented by a `SingularAttribute` while the `comments` and `tags` collections are represented by the JPA `ListAttribute`.

### PostDetails entity Metamodel

The `PostDetails` entity is mapped like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "post_details")
public class PostDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "created_on")
    private Date createdOn;

    @Column(name = "created_by")
    private String createdBy;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    private Post post;
    
    //Getters and setters omitted for brevity
}
```

All entity attributes are going to be represented by the JPA `SingularAttribute` in the associated `PostDetails_` Metamodel class:

```
@Generated(value = "org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor")
@StaticMetamodel(PostDetails.class)
public abstract class PostDetails_ {

    public static volatile SingularAttribute<PostDetails, Post> post;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<PostDetails, String> createdBy;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<PostDetails, Long> id;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<PostDetails, Date> createdOn;

    public static final String POST = "post";
    public static final String CREATED_BY = "createdBy";
    public static final String ID = "id";
    public static final String CREATED_ON = "createdOn";
}
```

### PostComment entity Metamodel

The `PostComment` is mapped as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "post_comment")
public class PostComment {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Post post;

    private String review;
    
    //Getters and setters omitted for brevity
}
```

And, all entity attributes are represented by the JPA `SingularAttribute` in the associated `PostComments_` Metamodel class:

```
@Generated(value = "org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor")
@StaticMetamodel(PostComment.class)
public abstract class PostComment_ {

    public static volatile SingularAttribute<PostComment, Post> post;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<PostComment, String> review;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<PostComment, Long> id;

    public static final String POST = "post";
    public static final String REVIEW = "review";
    public static final String ID = "id";
}
```

### Using the JPA Criteria Metamodel

Without the JPA Metamodel, a Criteria API query that needs to fetch the `PostComment` entities filtered by their associated `Post` title would look like this:

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();

CriteriaQuery<PostComment> query = builder.createQuery(PostComment.class);
Root<PostComment> postComment = query.from(PostComment.class);

Join<PostComment, Post> post = postComment.join("post");

query.where(
    builder.equal(
        post.get("title"),
        "High-Performance Java Persistence"
    )
);

List<PostComment> comments = entityManager
    .createQuery(query)
    .getResultList();
```

Notice that we used the `post` String literal when creating the `Join` instance, and we used the `title` String literal when referencing the `Post` `title`.

The JPA Metamodel allows us to avoid hard-coding entity attributes, as illustrated by the following example:

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();

CriteriaQuery<PostComment> query = builder.createQuery(PostComment.class);
Root<PostComment> postComment = query.from(PostComment.class);

Join<PostComment, Post> post = postComment.join(PostComment_.post);

query.where(
    builder.equal(
        post.get(Post_.title),
        "High-Performance Java Persistence"
    )
);

List<PostComment> comments = entityManager
    .createQuery(query)
    .getResultList();
```

Or, let's say we want to fetch a DTO projection while filtering the `Post` `title` and the `PostDetails` `createdOn` attributes.

We can use the Metamodel when creating the join attributes, as well as when building the DTO projection column aliases or when referencing the entity attributes we need to filter:

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();

CriteriaQuery<Object[]> query = builder.createQuery(Object[].class);

Root<PostComment> postComment = query.from(PostComment.class);
Join<PostComment, Post> post = postComment.join(PostComment_.post);

query.multiselect(
    postComment.get(PostComment_.id).alias(PostComment_.ID),
    postComment.get(PostComment_.review).alias(PostComment_.REVIEW),
    post.get(Post_.title).alias(Post_.TITLE)
);

query.where(
    builder.and(
        builder.like(
            post.get(Post_.title),
            "%Java Persistence%"
        ),
        builder.equal(
            post.get(Post_.details).get(PostDetails_.CREATED_BY),
            "Vlad Mihalcea"
        )
    )
);

List<PostCommentSummary> comments = entityManager
    .createQuery(query)
    .unwrap(Query.class)
    .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(PostCommentSummary.class))
    .getResultList();
```

Cool, right?

Answer (score 8):

For eclipselink, only the following dependency is sufficient to generate metamodel. Nothing else is needed.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: [Very important note: the metamodel is generated only if the entities are declared in the persistence unit. It doesn't work with discovered entities.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18336508/868879)

Comment: @Barthelomeus your note is **false**. EclipseLink 2.5.1+ will generate metamodel classes for unlisted entities too, just specify `<exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>` in persisetence.xml

Comment: Note that eclipselink won't generate without `persistence.xml`

Answer (score 6):

For Hibernate as provider which is most common IMHO:

In case of build tools like Gradle, Maven you need to have Hibernate JPA 2 Metamodel Generator jar in the classpath and compiler level>=1.6 that is all you need build the project and metamodel will be generated automatically.

In case of IDE Eclipse 
1. goto Project->Properties->Java Compiler->Annotation Processing and enable it. 
2. Expand Annotation Processing->Factory Path-> Add External Jar add Hibernate JPA 2 Metamodel Generator jar check the newly added jar and say OK. Clean and Build done!

Link Hibernate JPA 2 Metamodel Generator jar link from maven repo
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-jpamodelgen

Comment: In my case adding ```<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
    <scope>compile</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>``` to pom.xml was enough.

Comment: Do I need both configurations when using maven and Eclipse?

Comment: even though hibernate-jpamodelgen was added in the pom, i had to do this and it worked

Comment: This should also be the accepted answer. Thanks a lot Sandeep

Answer (score 1):

Ok, based on what I have read here, I did it with **EclipseLink** this way and I did not need to put the processor dependency to the project, only as an `annotationProcessorPath` element of the compiler plugin.

```
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <annotationProcessorPaths>
                <annotationProcessorPath>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
                    <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor</artifactId>
                    <version>2.7.7</version>
                </annotationProcessorPath>
            </annotationProcessorPaths>
            <compilerArgs>
                <arg>-Aeclipselink.persistencexml=src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml</arg>
            </compilerArgs>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69466221/hibernate-jpa-metamodel-generator-problem-with-filer-attempt-to-recreate-a-fi) for a minimal configuration with maven and how to deal with generated JPA metamodel source code in IDEs.

Answer (score 0):

Using Eclipse and Hibernate:

1. Got to menu Project > Properties > Project Facets;
2. Enable JPA facet version 2.1. It is enable a new menu JPA.
3. In menu JPA, in field Plataform choose "Hibernate (JPA 2.x)", in field JPA implementation choose "Disable Library Configuration" and in field Canonical Metamodel choose "src/main/java".