# Query object using Criteria Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying out a sample in Hibernate using Criteria.
Below are my tables :

```
CREATE TABLE  test.college (
  collegeId int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  collegeName varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (collegeId)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE  test.student (
  studentId int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  studentName varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  college_id int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (studentId),
  KEY FKF3371A1B11FE0A03 (college_id),
  CONSTRAINT FKF3371A1B11FE0A03 FOREIGN KEY (college_id) REFERENCES college (collegeId)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

So my entity classes are:

**College.Java**

```
package com.hibernate.onetomany;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

@Entity
public class College {

    private int collegeId;
    private String collegeName;
    private List<Student> students;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public int getCollegeId() {
        return collegeId;
    }
    public void setCollegeId(int collegeId) {
        this.collegeId = collegeId;
    }
    public String getCollegeName() {
        return collegeName;
    }
    public void setCollegeName(String collegeName) {
        this.collegeName = collegeName;
    }
    @OneToMany(targetEntity=Student.class,mappedBy="college",cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    public List<Student> getStudents() {
        return students;
    }
    public void setStudents(List<Student> students) {
        this.students = students;
    }
}
```

And my **Student.java**

```
package com.hibernate.onetomany;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;


@Entity
public class Student {

    private int studentId;
    private String studentName;
    private College college;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public int getStudentId() {
        return studentId;
    }
    public void setStudentId(int studentId) {
        this.studentId = studentId;
    }
    public String getStudentName() {
        return studentName;
    }
    public void setStudentName(String studentName) {
        this.studentName = studentName;
    }
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="college_id")
    public College getCollege() {
        return college;
    }
    public void setCollege(College college) {
        this.college = college;
    }

}
```

In the above example i have used one to many association.

Below is my main method:

**TestStudent.java**

```
package com.hibernate.onetomany;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions;

public class TestStudent {

    public static void main(String[] args){
            readRecords();
    }

    private static void readRecords() {
        SessionFactory factory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory(); 
        Session session = factory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        //Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(College.class,"college").createAlias("college.collegeId", "abc", JoinType.FULL_JOIN);
        Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(College.class).add(Restrictions.eq("collegeId", 2));


        List<College> collegeList = cr.list();

        for(College college : collegeList){
            System.out.println("CollegeID : " + college.getCollegeId());
            System.out.println("CollegeName : " + college.getCollegeName());
            List<Student> studentList = college.getStudents();
            for(Student student : studentList){
                System.out.println("StudentID : " + student.getStudentId());
                System.out.println("StudentName : " + student.getStudentName());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And my **hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
      "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
      "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">
            com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">
            jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/world</property>
        <property name="connection.username">user1</property>
        <property name="connection.password">password</property>
        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <mapping class="com.hibernate.onetomany.College" /> 
        <mapping class="com.hibernate.onetomany.Student" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Now the above example runs smooth and perfect. But i have a small requirement.
I have to pass a filter condition that is:
**Get the result set where studentName is : ABC**
So i want to filter the resultset using name of student.

In short i want to use the below piece of code to get the result:
**`Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(College.class).add(Restrictions.eq("studentName", "ABC"));`**

How can i achieve the above requirement using the same OneToMany approach?

Looking forward to your solutions.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you asking how to create a criteria-query with a join? If so, maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3424696/jpa-criteria-api-how-to-add-join-clause-as-general-sentence-as-possible

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But onetomany is doing the join only. I just want to filter the result from the join query using student name

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`@NamedQuery`](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-named-query-examples/) or [`@NamedNativeQuery`](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-named-query-examples/) :

```
@Entity
@NamedNativeQueries({
    @NamedNativeQuery(
        name = "college.findByStudentName",
        query = "SELECT * from test.college WHERE collegeId IN (SELECT college_id from test.student WHERE studentName = (:name))",
        resultClass = College.class
    )
)}
public class College {

    ...

}
```

**EDIT** :

here's how to use named queries :

```
List colleges = session.getNamedQuery("college.findByStudentName")
        .setString("name", "Linda Berry")
        .list();
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply FaNaj. I am getting exception while executing as: Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: name of: com.hibernate.onetomany.College and the restriction that i am passing is : Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(College.class).add(Restrictions.eq("name", "Linda Berry"));

Comment: i am able to run the above example that you suggested. But i am not getting the specific result.