# how to join two tables using hibernate createQuery or criteriaQuery how to map using annotation

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria, criteriaquery, createquery

```
package com.employee;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;

@Entity
@Table(name ="Employee")
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "sequence")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequence", sequenceName = "seq1", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "SYS_I")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "emp_id")
    private String empId;

    @Column(name = "emp_name")
    private String empName;

    @Column(name = "branch")
    private String emp_branch;

    @Column(name = "course")
    private String course;

    @Column(name = "head")
    private String head;


}

package com.employeebranch;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;

@Entity
@Table(name ="EmployeeBranch")
public class EmployeeBranch {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "branchSequence")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "branchSequence", sequenceName = "bran_seq1", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "SYS_I")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "emp_branch")
    private String emp_branch;

    @Column(name = "emp_course")
    private String course;

    @Column(name = "emp_head")
    private String empHead;

}enter image description here
```

Can anyone show how i can map fields using anotations like @OneToOne or @OneToMany or @ManyToOne. What kind of relationship it is in this condition?

So now here in emplpoyee branch table the value are like below.
id  emp_branch  emp_course   emp_head 
1   mechanical  physics     Principal
2   mechanical  chemistry   Headmaster
3   electrical  physics     Principal
4   electrical  chemistry   Headmaster

and in employee table the values are like below.
id   emp_id   emp_name   branch     course      head
1     10       sachin   mechanical  physics    001
4     12      Yuvraaj   mechanical  chemistry  002[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPK65.png)

select e.*, b.emp_head from EmployeeBranch b , Employee e where e.branch=b.emp_branch
and e.course = b.emp_course and e.branch = 'mechanical';

I want to  set this resultant results in Employee entity using createQuery. How can i achecive this?

Note: I want only with using criteria or createQuery by mapping onetomany or onetoone or manytoone. I am confused when data is of above type. i dont want using  JPA repository or  HQL or Native query

Comment: Please see the image for table values to get the relation between the tables

Comment: In employee table the head values are 001 and 002 instead of principal and headmaster

Comment: [JPA Criteria API - How to add JOIN clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3424696/jpa-criteria-api-how-to-add-join-clause-as-general-sentence-as-possible)