# Question: Specification Query Syntax For ManyToMany entities

Tags: spring, jpa, many-to-many, specifications, criteria-api

I want to find All the objects of class A (class A has a Many To Many Relationship with class B) , which have at least one Object of the Set of the Objects of Class B with a certain value in a field .

I had searched around the internet and for Documentation though i can take the way around ,creating a list of invoices that the Summary describes but I was curious if I will be able to write with pure Specification.

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "A.name")
 public class A {
   private Set<B> b; 
 }

@JoinTable(name = "AB",
joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "B_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},                 
inverseJoinColumns ={@JoinColumn(name= "A_id",referencedColumnName="id")})
@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
 public class B
 {
     private Object certainField;
     private Set<A> a;
 }

 public static Specification<A> hasB(Set<B> b) {
     return (a, cq, cb) -> {

         //I want to find all the Objects<A> which have an Element B with 
        // CertainField.equals(aValue);
       //     I find it hard to understand the syntax and i find no clue how 
     // to 
    //     make it work. 

    };
}
```

EDIT: Finally I found out. Criteria Builder more or less is an abstraction of an query in db in Sql. Thus the asnwer is JOIN.

```
 public static Specification<A> hasB(Set<B> b) {
          return (a, cq, cb) -> {
        SetJoin<A,B> jointENTITY  = a.joinSet("B")
         return cb.equal(jointEntity.get("certainField"),certainValue));
      };      
 }
```

Also a very helpful answer is this one: [JPA Criteria API - How to add JOIN clause (as general sentence as possible)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3424696/jpa-criteria-api-how-to-add-join-clause-as-general-sentence-as-possible)

Comment: CriteriaAPI is a terrible thing for sure. How would you do it with JPQL or SQL?

Comment: @Simon Martinelli I can and I did make my a way around the problem for time pressuring reasons ,but for consistency I would like to  know for refactor/curiosity  purposes.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli if you are still interensted, i found some time to write a proper answer to the question .