# How to use multiple JOINs with CriteriaBuilder to build Predicate?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data, specifications, criteriaquery

I have table A that has an attribute that is an entity in table B that in turn is connected to a table C.

The (working) SQL query looks like this:

```
SELECT a.* from A a
LEFT JOIN B b ON a.b_id=b.id
LEFT JOIN C c ON b.c_id=c.id where c.attribute=VALUE;
```

Basically the VALUE is what Im filtering on. There is a one-to-one relationship from A->B and a one-to-one relationship from B->C.

There are other parameters Im also filtering on so I have a `Specification` class that generates a `Predicate` for each parameter that is passed in to build a list of predicates which is then ANDed together at the end. The `Specification` is being called from my `Repository` using something like `findAll(MySpecificationClass.search(params))`.

Im having a hard time understanding how to write this SQL query using `CriteriaBuilder` inside my `Specification` class.

NOTES:

1. This is in a Spring Boot application written in Kotlin.
2. My specification class is a singleton so I can't autowire `EntityManager` for example.
3. I tried to use a chain of `get()`s to navigate from A, through B to C but that doesn't work - it seems to return all records regardless.
4. My project is using spring-data-jpa 2.2.6

Comment: [is this question helpful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3424696)

Comment: Not sure what you mean - Im trying to solve a problem and have not found any useful answers in any documentation, examples or blog posts. Are only certain kinds of questions "allowed" ?

Comment: It's a link to another SO question. I think your question is a good one.

Comment: Oh right, sorry I misunderstood :-) I read that earlier today and read some of the pages linked there. Im not using Metamodel API which gets mentioned there and in linked docs. I also can't use EntityManager which is used in many examples. It seems to me Criteria API is just not well documented and hard to grok.

Answer (score 0):

Through the help of a colleague I was able to build this (also should have been INNER JOINS).

The specific predicate returned from my `Specification` class is:

```
val joinToB: Join<A, B> = root.join("B", JoinType.INNER)
val joinToC: Join<B, C> = joinToB.join("C", JoinType.INNER)
cb.equal(joinToC.get<Long>("attribute"), VALUE)
```