# Annotation processing with Maven and Java 5 (JPA)

Tags: java, maven-2, jpa, annotations, jpa-2.0

I would like to use Criteria API in my new project and from what I understood, I also need to do annotation processing. Since there Java 5 on the server, how is this possible using Java 5 and Maven?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The annotation processing API from Java 6 (JSR 269) is different different from Java 5 (JSR 175) and I don't think you can run a Java 6 [`Processor`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/Processor.html) using the `apt` command from Java 5 (and I assume the [various implementations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037593/how-to-generate-jpa-2-0-metamodel) are all using the Java 6 API).

So your options are IMO:

- write your own static meta model generator using the Java 5 API (if possible?) and use the [apt-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/apt-maven-plugin/)
- builds on Java 6 with a Java 5 target and either use the maven-compiler-plugin support or the [maven-annotation-plugin](http://code.google.com/p/maven-annotation-plugin/) (see for example [this blog post](http://relation.to/16308.lace) - and the comments)
- generate the classes on another machine (with Java 6 available) and check them in your VCS.

Depending on what's possible for you and the chosen implementation, I could expend the Maven part if required.