# Eclipse Indigo, how to autogenerate Entity Meta Model

Tags: eclipse, metamodel

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037593/how-to-generate-jpa-2-0-metamodel) on how to auto-generate the Entity Meta Model, but I think there is something wrong.

I have: Eclipse Indigo SR2, build 20120216-1857 and configured the "Annotation Processor" as specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037593/how-to-generate-jpa-2-0-metamodel). To the factory path I have added ONLY these jars

- hibernate-jpamodelgen-1.2.0.Final.jar (taken from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hibernate/files/hibernate-jpamodelgen/))
- hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar (taken from the zip archive of Hibernate ORM 4.1.0 from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hibernate/files/hibernate4/))

I suppose after configuring this for my the EJB project (I did not do that for my Web or EAR Project), the project gets rebuild and the Meta Model Classes will be autogenerated, without clicking on another button, is that right?

If everything should have worked, do you have any clues on what could go wrong?
Notes:

- I see absolutely no messages from any annotation processors in the "Error Log" Eclipse View.
- My persistence.xml file is in the ejbModule/META-INF/persistence.xml
- All my entities extend an Abstract class, imported in the project with svn:externals.
- My entities are annotated with @Entity, and that's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the project has also AspectJ compatibility, which makes the Project use another compiler. More details on this bug [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=169857).

Beside that, you could (bun not mandatory you will) get an NullPointerException (see the "Error Log" Eclipse View) if you have at least an Abstract Class in your project.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to select the source folder of the generated metamodel on your Project -> Properties -> JPA