# Maven 3 - How to add annotation processor dependency?

Tags: java, maven, jpa-2.0, maven-3, annotation-processing

I need to run an annotation processor on my project's sources. The annotation processor should not become a transitive dependency of the project since it's only needed for annotation processing and nothing else.

Here is the complete (non-working) test pom I use for this:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>test</groupId>
  <artifactId>test</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Test annotations</name>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <hibernate-jpamodelgen.version>1.2.0.Final</hibernate-jpamodelgen.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax</groupId>
      <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
      <version>6.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <annotationProcessors>
            <annotationProcessor>
              org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor</annotationProcessor>
          </annotationProcessors>
          <debug>true</debug>
          <optimize>true</optimize>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
          <compilerArguments>
            <AaddGeneratedAnnotation>true</AaddGeneratedAnnotation>
            <Adebug>true</Adebug>
          </compilerArguments>
        </configuration>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-jpamodelgen.version}</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

I explicitly defined `org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor` as an annotation processor in the plugin configuration for tests and I know it shouldn't be required.

The problem I'm encountering is that the `hibernate-jpamodelgen` dependency is not added to the compiler classpath so the annotation processor is not found and the build fails.

As per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11245730/1030527), I tried adding the dependency as a build extension (not sure I understand what those are supposed to be!) like so:

```xml
<extensions>
  <extension>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate-jpamodelgen.version}</version>
  </extension>
</extensions>
```

This also doesn't add `hibernate-jpamodelgen` to the compiler classpath.

The only thing I found which works so far is adding the dependency to the project in the `<dependencies>` section. This has the unfortunate side-effect of adding `hibernate-jpamodelgen` as a transitive dependency afterwards which I want to avoid.

My previous working setup uses the `maven-processor-plugin` plugin to achieve what I want. However, this plugin is not supported by eclipse m2e and the latest version of the `maven-compiler-plugin` now handles multiple compiler arguments properly so I'd rather use the latter.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Add the dependency as an [optional dependency](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html) (`<optional>true</optional>`). This will add the dependency under compilation, but will prevent it for being a transitive dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
  <version>${hibernate-jpamodelgen.version}</version>
  <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

If you're creating an artifact in this module with all your dependencies in it (like a .war), you may use the `<scope>provided</scope>` instead. This both prevents the dependency to be transitive and to be included in the artifact the module produces.

Comment: Thanks this works! However, based on the Maven doc regarding scopes, this doesn't seem like the intended usage of `optional` and `provided`. I'll accept your answer (hey it works!) if no "better" answer comes up.

Comment: Also, it looks like `provided` will always do the right thing whereas `optional` won't with `war` packaging. Do you see any case where `provided` would fail?

Comment: Nope, I guess provided will always do the right thing for you. I also agree that it doesn't sounds right with "provided", but I guess you wont find any better solution.

Comment: "Optional" just means it's not required by other projects which depend on this one. If they want it, they have to declare it explicitly. Usually other projects won't want your annotation processors, so it's optional (not required).

For annotation processors to work, javac finds them on the compile-time classpath, which is the compile scope in maven.

"provided" is a special scope for some plugins which package/bundle compile-time dependencies. They are often confused, but it's easier if you think about what other projects need from your project, when they depend on yours.

Comment: In version 3.5 of the Maven compiler plug-in a new "annotationProcessorPaths" option was introduced. I recommend to use that (see my answer below) instead of exposing the processor JAR as a project dependency.

Comment: Something to keep in mind with "annotationProcessorPaths" is that it might be unintentionally overriding processors from a parent POM. `<annotationProcessorPaths combine.children="append">` in the child POM makes sure that the already configured ones are preserved.

Answer (score 45):

The [annotationProcessorPaths](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#annotationProcessorPaths) option can be used in recent versions of the Maven compiler plug-in:

```
<pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <annotationProcessorPath>
                        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                        <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
                        <version>5.2.6.Final</version>
                    </annotationProcessorPath>
                </annotationProcessorPaths>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

That way the processor is separated from the actual project dependencies. This option is also picked up by the Eclipse M2E plug-in if annotation processing is enabled for the project.

Comment: For some reason, it does not help. Once I add annotation processor as dependency (compile time) it works as expected. However, it is just old way to resolve the issue. Am I correct that adding artifact in `<annotationProcessorPaths>` does not require add that artifact in dependency section also? Any idea what am I missing?

Comment: Is it `<annotationProcessorPath>` or `<path>`? The [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#annotationProcessorPaths) indicates the latter.

Comment: If I use `<annotationProcessorPaths>` to specify the dependencies, do I still need `<annotationProcessors>` to indicate the actual annotation processors to use? Or will they be discovered automatically? Or will only those annotation processor dependencies with a `META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor` file be auto-detected, and I need to include `<annotationProcessors>` for any others?

Answer (score 12):

For JDK 10 I really had to go a bit crazy to get it to work, Hoping someone finds this useful

```xml
<jaxb.version>2.3.0</jaxb.version>
<maven.hibernate.version>5.3.2.Final</maven.hibernate.version>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven.compiler.version}</version>
    <goals>
        <goal>compile</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/annotations</outputDirectory>
        <annotationProcessorPaths>
            <annotationProcessorPath>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.hibernate.version}</version>
            </annotationProcessorPath>
            <annotationProcessorPath>
                <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
                <version>${jaxb.version}</version>
            </annotationProcessorPath>
        </annotationProcessorPaths>
        <annotationProcessors>
            <annotationProcessor>org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor</annotationProcessor>
        </annotationProcessors>
        <compilerArgs>
            <arg>-AaddGeneratedAnnotation=false</arg>
        </compilerArgs>
        <compilerArguments>
            <AaddGeneratedAnnotation>false</AaddGeneratedAnnotation>
            <Adebug>true</Adebug>
        </compilerArguments>
        <failOnError>true</failOnError>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.hibernate.version}</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jaxb.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 10):

The problem is really in **3.*** version of the `maven-compiler-plugin`. It acts a bit different from the **2.*** version. In particular, it seems that `maven-compiler-plugin`**3.*** doesn't add its dependencies and build extensions to the classpath because it uses javax.tools instruments for running compile process. To get back the old behavior for `maven-compiler-plugin` you should use a new configuration property `forceJavacCompilerUse`:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.1</version>
<configuration>
    <forceJavacCompilerUse>true</forceJavacCompilerUse>
</configuration>
....
</plugin>
```

Comment: I added that flag and I am still getting the error with Hibernate JPAMetalModelEntityProcessor version 1.3.  I have a multi module maven build and the generated classes instead of going into parentmodule/submodule/target/... is going right into parentmodule there is just a com dir dumped there with the classes?  Any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 4):

### Please take a look [jpa-metamodels-with-maven](http://jinahya.wordpress.com/2014/03/29/jpa-metamodels-with-maven/)

For further visitors, I found that there are some significant changes in maven-compiler-plugin 3.x series.

This is how I do this. (I'm the one who you linked)

The point is that my solution does not work with those 3.x series of maven-compiler-plugin.

```xml
<project ...>

  <build>

    <extensions>
      <extension>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0.Final</version>
      </extension>
    </extensions>

    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version> <!-- See this? -->
      </plugin>
    </plugins>

  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it with compiler version 3.1?  It looks like the new aspectj 1.8.2 is built off of those tools, so they get pulled in anyway and break the build.  The generated files seem to be getting dumped in the base dir instead of the target directory.  The forceJavacCompilerUse doesn't seem to fix it for me either.

Comment: @haskovec I hope the situation is changed. See [jpa-metamodels-with-maven-example](https://github.com/jinahya/jpa-metamodels-with-maven-example).

Comment: That was a couple of jobs ago for me. I think I ended up ripping out the meta model generation entirely because it wasn't doing what I needed to do, so I just changed our code to no longer need it.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what kind of build error you got, but here is my case:
I got the following compile error in Idea:
`Annotation processor 'org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor' not found error`

But, when compiled from Maven, it was all fine.

So, the problem of mine was that somehow I got wrong configuration in Idea settings. Particularly, it appeared that Idea somehow detected the processor and put in into the settings of module processor profiles. [It is discussed here.](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-86561#comment=27-341952)

I fixed it as the following:

1. Go to Idea > Settings > Annotation Processors.
2. For each processor profile make sure that:

   - Enable annotation processing is Yes;
   - There is no annotation processor FQ name of one you have error about (e.i. "JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor") in the list on the right side. If it is listed there, just select and click '-' minus button to remove it.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is a better way to contain such dependencies in profiles to solve such problems.

```
<profile>
    <id>XXX-profile</id>
    <dependencies>
         <dependency>
             // XXX artifact path
         </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</profile>
```