# Parameter value [1] did not match expected type [java.lang.Boolean]

Tags: java, spring, hql

I'm getting the error `Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter value [1] did not match expected type [java.lang.Boolean]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [1] did not match expected type [java.lang.Boolean]`.

I'm confused by this because it's coming from the service method shown below that is commented out.  When I comment it out, the error is avoided.  The `active` column is a `TINYINT(1)` that's either `1` or `0`.

Entity:

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name="Workflow.findByUUID", query="SELECT w FROM Workflow w WHERE w.uuid = :uuid"),
        @NamedQuery(name="Workflow.findByActive", query="SELECT w FROM Workflow w WHERE w.active = :active ORDER BY id ASC")
})
```

My Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface WorkflowRepository extends JpaRepository<Workflow, Integer> {
    List<Workflow> findByActive(@Param("active") Integer active);
}
```

My Service:

```
@Service
public class WorkflowService {

    @Autowired
    WorkflowRepository workflowRepository;

    /**
     * Get active workflows
     */
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<Workflow> findActive() {
        //return workflowRepository.findByActive(1);
        return null;
    }
```

When I uncomment

Comment: In terms of JPA entities the parameter is boolean. The question is tagged with `hql` :-), there are no tinyints in java. `@NamedQueries` are in java persistence language, I think.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You seem to have mapped `Workflow.active` attribute as a `Boolean`. So you repository should be like:

```
@Repository
public interface WorkflowRepository extends JpaRepository<Workflow, Boolean> {
    List<Workflow> findByActive(@Param("active") Boolean active);
}
```

And the call `workflowRepository.findByActive(true)` should behave how you want it to.

The fact is that HQL sometimes make a type difference between database and Java mapping, because typing isn't the same in these environments. So check your `Entity`'s `active` type to make the appropriate `Repository`.

Comment: blint, what's the purpose of the `@Param("active")` annotation?

Comment: @AlexanderSuraphel `@Param` lets you configure the name of the parameter in target query.

Comment: I thought it was not needed. I was doing sth like http://stackoverflow.com/a/35179837/1242842.

Comment: I am using `Specification` for this, but it's not working