# Spring Data Rest findByIdIn

Tags: spring-data-rest

We use Spring Data Rest to build simple API for our internal webapp.
Our repositories as below:

```
public interface BaseRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> {
  List<T> findByIdIn(@Param("ids") Collection<ID> ids);
}

public interface FooRepository extends BaseRepository<Foo, String> {}
public interface BarRepository extends BaseRepository<Bar, Long> {}
```

Our client fetch data, passing ids parameters as below:

1. GET http://example.com/api/foos/search/findByIdIn?ids=ABC,XYZ --> It works well for String ids.
2. GET http://example.com/api/bars/search/findByIdIn?ids=1,2,3 --> Got exception for numeric ids.

We got the exception: Parameter value element[1] did not match expected type [java.lang.Long (n/a)]

What's wrong with above repositories? What is the correct way to pass numeric ids?

Comment: You haven't added the API code, Numeric ids might be coming in string format, parse it to Long.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parameter value \[1\] did not match expected type \[java.lang.Boolean\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15791139/parameter-value-1-did-not-match-expected-type-java-lang-boolean)

Answer (score 0):

You may use this library which lets you build advanced search queries: https://github.com/turkraft/spring-filter

You can then simply do:

> ?filter= **ids in (1, 2, 3, 4)**

It supports enums, dates, booleans, logical operations, comparisons, and even joins (nested fields).