# Find an object in Hibernate without id

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm using Spring.
I have a user table.

When a person logins to the system, he sends me his credentials (i.e. username and password).

I stored my users in database with "incremental generated uid" (i.e. userid is primary key).

I also stored the username password etc. in the database. What I need to do is, when the user connects to the Rest connection, I need to check whether the database has this user or not. If he exists, then I need to check if passwords are matching. And I need to do that checking by username, rather than uid

I dont have session or anything at all in my program (Or as far as I know, I didn't write any session or sessionfactory in my code at all)

My repository class:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>{
}
```

My user DAO

```
@Service
public class UserDAO {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    public User findByUsername(String username)
    {
        //what to write here

    }
}
```

I've looked up [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14977018/jpa-how-to-get-entity-based-on-field-value-other-than-id) but as I stated above, I don't have session.

Comment: Remove your `UserDAO`... Put the `findByUsername` method in `UserRepository` and well that is it. Also instead of re-inventing the security wheel I suggest using Spring Security instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring does provide all the necessary Dependencies and functions you do need.

Coming back to your question. You can easily query for non-id fields in Spring by just providing a Repository and in there method Signatures with a certain Naming convention to provide the appropriate Result.

You can inject `EntityManager`, which gives you access to the `Session` as well, using `@PersistenceContex`t which will inject shared `EntityManager` managed by Spring

Furthermore you can use the Naming Convention Thingy by extending your `UserRepository` from `Repository` (or any child of it), like you are already doing, and provide a method signature like `findBy<FIELDNAME>(String value)`, eg. `findByUsername(String username)`.

If you do use the Repository-approach, you do not need to implement a DAO.

For a detailed description, take a look at the [Reference Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.definition) of Spring.

Comment: You don't need `@Repository` on the `UserRepository`.