# Java Criteria API query for bridge table with composite primary key

Tags: java, criteria

What is the Java criteria api query equivalent of the following SQL? I am new to this and have tried a few things but none worked.

```
SELECT p.* FROM Product p
RIGHT JOIN store_has_product shp ON  p.id_product=shp.id_product
WHERE shp.id_store=1;
```

TableA: store

Bridge Table: store_has_product (table has id_store, id_product as composite pk)

TableB: product

Entities (without constructors, getters/setters)

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "product")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Product.findAll", query = "SELECT p FROM Product p"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Product.findByIdProduct", query = "SELECT p FROM Product p WHERE p.idProduct = :idProduct"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Product.findByName", query = "SELECT p FROM Product p WHERE p.name = :name"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Product.findByCost", query = "SELECT p FROM Product p WHERE p.cost = :cost")})
public class Product implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "idProduct")
    private Integer idProduct;
    @Size(max = 45)
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    // @Max(value=?)  @Min(value=?)//if you know range of your decimal fields consider using these annotations to enforce field validation
    @Column(name = "cost")
    private Double cost;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "product")
    private Collection<StoreHasProduct> storeHasProductCollection;

@Entity
@Table(name = "store")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Store.findAll", query = "SELECT s FROM Store s"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Store.findByIdStore", query = "SELECT s FROM Store s WHERE s.idStore = :idStore"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Store.findByName", query = "SELECT s FROM Store s WHERE s.name = :name")})
public class Store implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "idStore")
    private Integer idStore;
    @Size(max = 45)
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "store")
    private Collection<StoreHasProduct> storeHasProductCollection;

@Entity
@Table(name = "store_has_product")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "StoreHasProduct.findAll", query = "SELECT s FROM StoreHasProduct s"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "StoreHasProduct.findByStoreidStore", query = "SELECT s FROM StoreHasProduct s WHERE s.storeHasProductPK.storeidStore = :storeidStore"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "StoreHasProduct.findByProductidProduct", query = "SELECT s FROM StoreHasProduct s WHERE s.storeHasProductPK.productidProduct = :productidProduct"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "StoreHasProduct.findByActive", query = "SELECT s FROM StoreHasProduct s WHERE s.active = :active")})
public class StoreHasProduct implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @EmbeddedId
    protected StoreHasProductPK storeHasProductPK;
    @Column(name = "active")
    private Short active;
    @JoinColumn(name = "Product_idProduct", referencedColumnName = "idProduct", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Product product;
    @JoinColumn(name = "Store_idStore", referencedColumnName = "idStore", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Store store;

@Embeddable
public class StoreHasProductPK implements Serializable {
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "Store_idStore")
    private int storeidStore;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "Product_idProduct")
    private int productidProduct;
```

Metamodel

```
@Generated(value = "org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor")
@StaticMetamodel(Product.class)
public abstract class Product_ {

    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Product, Double> cost;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Product, String> name;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Product, Integer> idProduct;
    public static volatile CollectionAttribute<Product, StoreHasProduct> storeHasProductCollection;

}

@Generated(value = "org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor")
@StaticMetamodel(Store.class)
public abstract class Store_ {

    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Store, String> name;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Store, Integer> idStore;
    public static volatile CollectionAttribute<Store, StoreHasProduct> storeHasProductCollection;

}

@Generated(value = "org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor")
@StaticMetamodel(StoreHasProduct.class)
public abstract class StoreHasProduct_ {

    public static volatile SingularAttribute<StoreHasProduct, Product> product;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<StoreHasProduct, Short> active;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<StoreHasProduct, Store> store;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<StoreHasProduct, StoreHasProductPK> storeHasProductPK;

}

@Generated(value = "org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor")
@StaticMetamodel(StoreHasProductPK.class)
public abstract class StoreHasProductPK_ {

    public static volatile SingularAttribute<StoreHasProductPK, Integer> productidProduct;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<StoreHasProductPK, Integer> storeidStore;

}
```

Edit* Question: Is it possible to use it as a specification? I don't even know if I am doing the right thing regarding the predicate but here is what I am attempting:

```
Integer resultsPerPage = 20;
    Sort.Direction sortOrder = Sort.Direction.DESC;
    String sortBy = "name";
    PageRequest request
            = new PageRequest(1 - 1, resultsPerPage, sortOrder, sortBy);
    Page<Product> prods = productRepository.findAll(where(productBelongsToStore("Tesco")), request);

    for (Product prod : prods.getContent()) {
        System.out.println(""+ prod.getName());
    }
```

Specification:

```
public static Specification<Product> productBelongsToStore(final String searchTerm) {
    return new Specification<Product>() {
        @Override
        public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Product> root, CriteriaQuery<?> cq, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
            String likePattern = SpecificationUtilityMethods.getLikePattern(searchTerm);
            Root<Product> product = cq.from(Product.class);
            Join<Product, StoreHasProduct> storeHasProduct = product.join(Product_.storeHasProductCollection);
            Path<Store> storeName = storeHasProduct.get(StoreHasProduct_.store);
            return cb.like(cb.lower(storeName.<String>get(Store_.name)), likePattern);

        }
    };
}
```

This outputs:
Milk
Milk
Juice
Juice
Cereal
Cereal
Butter
Butter
Bread
Bread

Which is wrong

*For anyone attempting the same thing I fixed this by removing "Root product = cq.from(Product.class);" and just using the root parameter.

Comment: Please add the code for what you have tried already. show the effort (-:

Comment: Do you have any Metamodel classes generated? It's usually easier then. And what does the entity objects for `Store` and `Product`look like? You can skip getters/setters when listing the entity classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Product> query = cb.createQuery(Product.class);

// "FROM Product p"
Root<Product> product = query.from(Product.class);
// "RIGHT JOIN store_has_product shp", "ON p.id_product=shp.id_product" is handled inside Product.class
Join<Product,StoreHasProduct> storeHasProduct = product.join(Product_.storeHasProductCollection);
// Create an alias to the shp.id_store column to use in the where condition
Path<Integer> id = storeHasProduct.get(StoreHasProduct_.storeHasProductPK).get(StoreHasProductPK_.storeidStore);
// "WHERE shp.id_store = 1"
query.where(cb.equal(id, 1));
// "SELECT p.*"
query.select(product);

TypedQuery<Product> tq = entityManager.createQuery(query);
for (Product p : tq.getResultList()) {
    // do stuff
}
```

This is from top of my head and the code is untested, so I hope I haven't made any major errors.

This can be solved without meta model classes as well, but you risk making a mistake when entering column names as strings. Something that the compiler can't catch. With meta models, the compiler can catch more errors that may be missed otherwise.

Comment: Thank you, I will have to look into this in more detail once I get home. I don't have metamodel classes as I am not sure how to generate them. Is it possible to include this into a repository so that I can utilise the specification and pageable features?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037593/how-to-generate-jpa-2-0-metamodel) question about how to generate metamodel classes.

Comment: Hey I added more details about the entities and metamodel, I couldn't get the join to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Thank you so much! That did work and helped me learn. I have edited my post with an additional question if you have some time :)

Comment: I think it's better that you ask a new question about that part. That will get more attention from potential helpers. I have not used `Specification`.

Comment: Thats okay, it kind of works now when I removed the product root and just used the one from the parameter. Thanks again.