# JPA - How to query with a LIKE operator in combination with an AttributeConverter

Tags: java, jpa, criteria-api

For example `Customer` has a field of type `PhoneNumber` (value object).
In the `persistence.xml` a `PhoneNumberConverter` is registered which implements `javax.persistence.AttributeConverter`. This converter converts a `PhoneNumber` to string and visa versa, so the JPA provider is able to store `PhoneNumbers` into the database.

How to query a `Customer` with a `LIKE` operator on `PhoneNumber` with the Criteria API? `PhoneNumber` can only be a valid phone number. A `PhoneNumber` with a value like `'+31%'` is not possible.

Comment: Did you try to use in NamedQuery?

Comment: @Safwan Hijazi The use of `Predicates` within the Criteria API comes in handy implementing a large form for searching 'Customers'. When a field is left empty, it shouldn't be taken in account when querying `Customers`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple answer is to use a `NamedQuery`, but you could also use a `CriteriaBuilder`. Note that you will have to provide the correct types and search terms.

Something like this:

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Tuple> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createTupleQuery();
Root root = criteriaQuery.from(/*The class youre searching*/);
Predicate predicate = criteriaBuilder.like(root.<String>get(/*field name*/), /*search values*/);
criteriaQuery.where(predicate);
criteriaQuery.select(root);
TypedQuery query = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
List<T> result = query.getResultList();
```

Comment: All credits to user489041. I added an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30726266/868879) which continues the example with Customer for completeness.

Answer (score 3):

```
public List<Customer> findCustomerByPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
    EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Customer> cq = criteriaBuilder.createQuery();
    Root<Customer> customer = criteriaQuery.from(Customer.class);
    Predicate predicate = cb.like(customer.get(Customer_.phoneNumber).as(String.class), phoneNumber);
    cq.where(predicate);
    TypedQuery<Customer> query = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);

    return query.getResultList();
    }
```

Where `phoneNumber` may include the character `%`.
The solution of the problem is in the casting to `String` of `PhoneNumber`: `.as(String.class)`. `PhoneNumber` has to override the methode `toString ()` and return the phone number.

(`Customer_` provides the meta model of `Customer` and may be generated by a [metamodel generator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3037593/868879).)

Comment: Beware of _.as_, it will generate _cast()_ in your query, possibly preventing it from using index.

Comment: @chimmi Would it still do this is the db datatype of the column is text? My issue is similar to the OP's except the db datatype was specifically chosen to be text to permit efficient 'like' queries. Works fine in native queries but now I need to use the Criteria API for ad-hoc form-based filtering.

Comment: Most likely. But you should really check for yourself, just try it with logs enabled and see what sql is being executed.