# JPA CriteriaBuilder value like column

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, criteria-api

I'm trying to create a query using CriteriaBuilder where I need to have a predicate where the value of the predicate is like the value in the database.

Basically, I need to be able to do the following:
`WHERE myTestValue LIKE columnValue`

In native queries, it is an option to do that, but using the CriteriaBuilder or NamedQueries, it does not seem to work.

```
String myValue = "foo@bar.com";
cb.where(cb.like(myValue, root.get(Entity_.email));
```

Is there an option in JPA to do it like this? Or should I fall back to native queries?

**EDIT**
I need to be able to check if a given value matches a wildcard entry in database. So the database has a record `%@bar.com%`, and I need to check if my given value `foo@bar.com` matches to that record.

Comment: Maybe you have forgot to add "%" at the beginning and at the end of your test string?

Comment: Do you get any errors? or it just does not work..

Comment: It just does not compile. JPA does not like to do it this way ;)

Comment: Show what it complains about.  You also might first try JPQL to verify it'll work there.  If it doesn't like the string, try passing it in as a parameter instead cb.where(cb.like(cb.parameter(String.class, "myValueParameter"), root.get(Entity_.email)); and then set the parameter in the query query.setParameter("myValueParameter", myValue);

Answer (score 5):

I think your params should be other way round:

```
cb.where(cb.like(root.get(Entity_.email),myValue);
```

Aditionally you may need to use add this to the second param:

```
cb.where(cb.like(root.get(Entity_.email),"%"+myValue+"%");
```

Comment: I need them to be in this order. I need to check if a given email address matches on a wildcard entry in the database.

Comment: Found similar question may this help. 
http://stackoverflow.com/q/30718445/3136973

Comment: That's just an example of how to implement `WHERE columnValue LIKE myTestValue`, I need it vice versa `WHERE myTestValue LIKE columnValue`

Comment: I see, i will try to do some tests later on some live environment. Are you using JPA 2.1? And EclispeLink version?

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. This is for column-like-value.

Answer (score 2):

Chris found the answer. First I need to "generate" a parameter.

```
ParameterExpression<String> senderEmailParameter = cb.parameter(String.class, "senderEmailParameter");
Path<String> senderEmailPath = root.get(Entity_.senderEmail);

Predicate predEmail = cb.like(senderEmailParameter, senderEmailPath);
```

And then I need to fill the parameter in the query.

```
q.where(predEmail);

return em.createQuery(q).setParameter("senderEmailParameter", senderEmail).getSingleResult();
```

This works! Thanks Chris!

Comment: This worked for me with JPA, hibernate and spring boot 2.1.9, thank you!