# Java Jpa Custom entity attribute converter and Specification

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

In my Java code, I have a JPA entity define as below

```
public class Entity {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    ... other attributes;

    @Column(name = "ctx")
    @Convert(converter = MapToJsonStringConverter.class)
    private Map<String, String> ctx;
}

@Convert
public class MapToJsonStringConverter implements AttributeConverter<Map<String, String>, String> {

    @Autowired
    private JsonParserService jsonParserService;

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(final Map<String, String> map) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(map)
                .map(jsonParserService::writeValueAsString)
                .orElse(null);
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> convertToEntityAttribute(final String string) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(string)
                .map(jsonParserService::readValueAsMap)
                .orElse(null);
    }
}
```

A Jpa attribute converter is used to convert the `ctx` attribute to/ from a JSON string. I need to create a JPA specification that allows me to query the `ctx` field in the database using a `LIKE` clause:

```
ctx LIKE '%test-value%'
```

Of course, when I try to create such specification the criteria builder cannot match the type of the attribute as it is expecting a map when instead I only supply a string

```
cb.like(root.get(Entity_.ctx), string))  <--- compile error Cannot resolve method 'like(javax.persistence.criteria.Expression<M>, java.lang.String)'
```

Is there a way to make this work instead of using a native query? Consider that the final specification also involves other attributes of the same entity.

Comment: `ctx` is a `String`. Can you provide `MapToJsonStringConverter` ?

Comment: Updated original post

Comment: Please provide examples of `ctx`

Comment: Its a String containing a json map of key value attributes -> `{ "key": "value", "anotherKey": "anotherValue"}`

Comment: Did you try `cb.like(root.get(Entity_.ctx).as(String.class), string)` ? Mentionned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30726266/11825162)

Comment: Trying something similar `cb.like(root.<String>get("ctx"), clause)`

Comment: This does not work `cb.like(root.<String>get("ctx"), clause)` instead `cb.like(root.get(Entity_.ctx).as(String.class), string)` does

Answer (score 1):

As mentionned in commentaries

```java
cb.like(root.<String>get("ctx"), clause);
```

Does not work as `root.get(Entity_.ctx)` or its equivalent does return a `Map<String, String>` and explicitly typing the generic (`<String>get(...)`) won't help as `Map` is not `instanceof` `String`.
The solution as mentionned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30718445/jpa-how-to-query-with-a-like-operator-in-combination-with-an-attributeconverte/30726266#30726266) is to use `as` provided by Criteria.

```java
cb.like(root.get(Entity_.ctx).as(String.class), string)
```

It does work thanks to `Map` overriding `Object.toString()`.
Otherwise you would need to create your own class extending `Map` and custom the override to `toString()` to return your custom representation (which is used by default by Json libs).

Comment: Just one more on this specific answer, this essentially works fine but at the same time it is casting to a VARCHAR(255) meaning that the column is truncated during the search. Is there a way to cast that to a TEXT ?