# How to write a Hibernate join condition?

Tags: hibernate, hql

There are two beans : Dept and User. They map respectively table department and table employees :

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "HR.EMPLOYEES")
    public class User {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="EMPLOYEES_SEQ", sequenceName="EMPLOYEES_SEQ", allocationSize=1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="EMPLOYEES_SEQ")
    @Column(name = "EMPLOYEE_ID")
    private int uid;

    @Formula(value="FIRST_NAME || ' ' || LAST_NAME")
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME")
    private String firstname;

    @Column(name = "LAST_NAME")
    private String lastname;

    @Column(name="EMAIL")
    private String email;

    @Column(name="HIRE_DATE")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
    private Date hireDate;

    private String job_id;

    @Column(name = "SALARY")
    private double salary;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "DEPARTMENT_ID")
    private Dept dept;

    public int getUid() {
        return uid;
    }
    public void setUid(int id) {
        this.uid = id;
    }
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }
    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }
    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }
    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public Date getHireDate() {
        return hireDate;
    }
    public void setHireDate(Date hireDate) {
        this.hireDate = hireDate;
    }
    public String getJob_id() {
        return job_id;
    }
    public void setJob_id(String job_id) {
        this.job_id = job_id;
    }
    public double getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }
    public void setSalary(double salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }
    public Dept getDept() {
        return dept;
    }
    public void setDept(Dept dept) {
        this.dept = dept;
    }

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "HR.DEPARTMENTS")
public class Dept {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "DEPARTMENT_ID")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "DEPARTMENT_NAME")
    private String dname;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "dept")
    @Transient
    private Set<User> users = new HashSet<User>(0);

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDname() {
        return dname;
    }

    public void setDname(String dname) {
        this.dname = dname;
    }

    public Set<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(Set<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }

}
```

Service method :

```
@Override
@Transactional
public List<User> list(int start, int length, String search, int triIdx, String ordreTri) {

    String hql = "from User u join u.dept as d "; // here is the join condition

    if (search != null && !search.equals("")) {

        hql = hql.concat(" where ");

        if (NumberUtils.isNumber(search))
            hql = hql.concat(" u.salary ");
        else
            hql = hql.concat(" lower(u.username) ");

        hql = hql.concat(" like '%").concat(search.toLowerCase()).concat("%'");

    }

    if (ordreTri.equals("asc")) {

        switch (triIdx) {
            case 0:
                hql = hql.concat(" order by u.username ");
                break;
            case 1:
                hql = hql.concat(" order by u.email ");
                break;
            case 2:
                hql = hql.concat(" order by u.salary ");
                break;
            case 3:
                hql = hql.concat(" order by d.dname ");
                break;
            default:
                hql = hql.concat(" order by u.username ");
                break;
        }

    } else {

        switch (triIdx) {
            case 0:
                hql = hql.concat(" order by u.username desc");
                break;
            case 1:
                hql = hql.concat(" order by u.email desc");
                break;
            case 2:
                hql = hql.concat(" order by u.salary desc");
                break;
            case 3:
                hql = hql.concat(" order by d.dname desc");
                break;
            default:
                hql = hql.concat(" order by u.username desc");
                break;
        }
    }

    Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql);
    query = query.setFirstResult(start);
    query = query.setMaxResults(length);

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<User> listUser = (List<User>) query.list();
    return listUser;
}
```

dataTable :

```
...
"columns"       : [
                      {"data" : "username"},
                      {"data" : "email"},
                      {"data" : "salary"},
                      {"data" : "dname"},
                      {"data" : "uid"}
                  ],
...
```

I want to retrieve user columns and department name ; in standard SQL we can write : `select e.first_name , e.salary, d.department_name from emp e join dept d on e.dept_id = d.dept_id`

But how to write the join in Hibernate here ?

**EDIT :**

At runtime there is alert error : `DataTables warning: table id=t_list - Requested unknown parameter 'username' for row 0, column 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4`

Comment: do you want the specific columns? does `Criteria` object fit your needs? i mean, return the `User` object which has the `Dept` object as property.

Comment: ok if it is just hql, i guess you want `from User usr
JOIN FETCH usr.dept`

Comment: `@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "DEPARTMENT_ID")
    private Dept dept;`

Comment: any updates? did you find it?

Comment: can you post the exception and the new code?

Comment: ok , I updated the source codes , and provided the error.

Comment: ok this is `datatables` error. javascript-specific. nothing to do with the original question. does your hql return the data you want?

Comment: because of the datatable error nothing is displayed ! but I want to know if is the join condition correct this time ?

Comment: you can `sysout` the results and see if it works the way you want, before trying to display them in a chosen UI mode (datatables at this specific situation).

Comment: sysout works when running the app on the IDE preview. How to do it if the app runs on browser ?

Comment: so your query works as you asked for. that's what i wanted to know. this is a different question and you need to provide extra stuff about your templating engine, your html, js code etc. please accept an answer for this question to be considered closed. thnx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `hql`, you can write

```
from User usr JOIN FETCH usr.dept
```

If you want to use `Criteria` object, you can write

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = your_entity_manager_object.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery cq = cb.createQuery(User.class);
Root root = cq.from(User.class);
cq.select(root).distinct(true);
root.fetch(User_.dept, JoinType.INNER);
```

last line is valid only if you have enabled JPA 2.0 metamodel. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037593/how-to-generate-jpa-2-0-metamodel)