# Hibernate CriteriaBuilder to join multiple tables

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-criteria

I'm trying to join 4 tables using hibernate criteriabuilder..
Below are the tables respectively..
`

```
@Entity
public class BuildDetails {
    @Id
    private long id;
    @Column
    private String buildNumber; 
    @Column
    private String buildDuration;
    @Column
    private String projectName;

}   

@Entity
public class CodeQualityDetails{
    @Id
    private long id;
    @Column
    private String codeHealth;
    @ManyToOne
    private BuildDetails build; //columnName=buildNum
}

@Entity
public class DeploymentDetails{
    @Id
    private Long id;
    @Column
    private String deployedEnv;
    @ManyToOne
    private BuildDetails build; //columnName=buildNum
}

@Entity
public class TestDetails{
    @Id
    private Long id;
    @Column
    private String testStatus;
    @ManyToOne
    private BuildDetails build; //columnName=buildNum
}
```

---

In these 4 tables I would like to perform the below sql script for MySQL:

```
SELECT b.buildNumber, b.buildDuration,
       c.codeHealth, d.deployedEnv, t.testStatus
FROM BuildDetails b
INNER JOIN CodeQualityDetails c ON b.buildNumber=c.buildNum
INNER JOIN DeploymentDetails d ON b.buildNumber=d.buildNum
INNER JOIN TestDetails t ON b.buildNumber=t.buildNum
WHERE b.buildNumber='1.0.0.1' AND
      b.projectName='Tera'
```

---

So, How can I achieve this using Hibernate CriteriaBuilder? Please help...

Thanks in advance.......

Comment: the first question is, do you really need to use criteria here.. is this going to be a dynamic query.. or just the params will change?

Comment: yes I have to use CriteriaBuilder here.... and also parameters will change here

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery query = cb.createQuery(/* Your combined target type, e.g. MyQueriedBuildDetails.class, containing buildNumber, duration, code health, etc.*/);

Root<BuildDetails> buildDetailsTable = query.from(BuildDetails.class);
Join<BuildDetails, CopyQualityDetails> qualityJoin = buildDetailsTable.join(CopyQualityDetails_.build, JoinType.INNER);
Join<BuildDetails, DeploymentDetails> deploymentJoin = buildDetailsTable.join(DeploymentDetails_.build, JoinType.INNER);
Join<BuildDetails, TestDetails> testJoin = buildDetailsTable.join(TestDetails_.build, JoinType.INNER);

List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
predicates.add(cb.equal(buildDetailsTable.get(BuildDetails_.buildNumber), "1.0.0.1"));
predicates.add(cb.equal(buildDetailsTable.get(BuildDetails_.projectName), "Tera"));

query.multiselect(buildDetails.get(BuildDetails_.buildNumber),
                  buildDetails.get(BuildDetails_.buildDuration),
                  qualityJoin.get(CodeQualityDetails_.codeHealth),
                  deploymentJoin.get(DeploymentDetails_.deployedEnv),
                  testJoin.get(TestDetails_.testStatus));
query.where(predicates.stream().toArray(Predicate[]::new));

TypedQuery<MyQueriedBuildDetails> typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(query);

List<MyQueriedBuildDetails> resultList = typedQuery.getResultList();
```

I assume you built the JPA metamodel for your classes. If you don't have the metamodel or you simply don't want to use it, just replace `BuildDetails_.buildNumber` and the rest with the actual names of the column as `String`, e.g. `"buildNumber"`.

Note that I could not test the answer (was also writing it without editor support), but it should at least contain everything you need to know to build the query.

How to build your metamodel? Have a look at [hibernate tooling](http://hibernate.org/orm/tooling/) for that (or consult [How to generate JPA 2.0 metamodel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037593/how-to-generate-jpa-2-0-metamodel) for other alternatives). If you are using maven it can be as simple as just adding the `hibernate-jpamodelgen`-dependency to your build classpath. As I do not have any such project now available I am not so sure about the following (so take that with a grain of salt). It might suffice to just add the following as dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
  <version>5.3.7.Final</version>
  <scope>provided</scope> <!-- this might ensure that you do not package it, but that it is otherwise available; untested now, but I think I used it that way in the past -->
</dependency>
```

Comment: Speaking as a JPA newbie, it would REALLY help if this answer showed how to build or get the JPA metamodels.  Also when you write "actual name of the column" did you mean the entity class's field name (not the database column name)?

Comment: added a short explanation regarding how to generate that metamodel... note that I do not have any JPA-project available right now, so I can't really tell for sure... but it was definitely easy to generate... regarding name of the column vs class's field name: I think it is the latter... you may want to lookup the Javadoc for that (`Path.get(String)`)...

Comment: I've found a typo in this that might help others. 

    cb.equal(BuildDetails_.buildNumber, "1.0.0.1")
    cb.equal(BuildDetails_.projectName, "Tera")

Are incorrect. The should be
    cb.equal(buildDetailsTable.get(BuildDetails_.buildNumber, "1.0.0.1"))
    cb.equal(buildDetailsTable.get(BuildDetails_.projectName, "Tera"))

Comment: @MichaelRountree Sounds reasonable.. will update the answer to reflect it.. Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: @Roland Can you please answer on this one too https://stackoverflow.com/q/72602473/8663316

Comment: I',m sorry... hibernate is too far away for me now... don't have any project here to try it... isn't there a better message in the stack trace? you may want to link from your question to this answer here (if that might be helpful to understand your question), so others may have a better clue what's wrong...