# CriteriaQuery Using Hibernate 3.6.10

Tags: hibernate, criteria

I want to create a query using `CriteriaBuilder`. 
I am using `hibernate 3.6.10`

Structure of query will be similar to below 
 - [How to join Multiple tables using hibernate criteria where entity relationship is not direct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41982998/hibernate-criteriabuilder-to-join-multiple-tables)

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery query = cb.createQuery(/* Your combined target type, e.g. MyQueriedBuildDetails.class, containing buildNumber, duration, code health, etc.*/);

Root<BuildDetails> buildDetailsTable = query.from(BuildDetails.class);
Join<BuildDetails, CopyQualityDetails> qualityJoin = buildDetailsTable.join(CopyQualityDetails_.build, JoinType.INNER);
Join<BuildDetails, DeploymentDetails> deploymentJoin = buildDetailsTable.join(DeploymentDetails_.build, JoinType.INNER);
Join<BuildDetails, TestDetails> testJoin = buildDetailsTable.join(TestDetails_.build, JoinType.INNER);

List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
predicates.add(cb.equal(BuildDetails_.buildNumber, "1.0.0.1"));
predicates.add(cb.equal(BuildDetails_.projectName, "Tera"));

query.multiselect(buildDetails.get(BuildDetails_.buildNumber),
                  buildDetails.get(BuildDetails_.buildDuration),
                  qualityJoin.get(CodeQualityDetails_.codeHealth),
                  deploymentJoin.get(DeploymentDetails_.deployedEnv),
                  testJoin.get(TestDetails_.testStatus));
query.where(predicates.stream().toArray(Predicate[]::new));

TypedQuery<MyQueriedBuildDetails> typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(query);
```

But as I am not using `JPA` , I cannot use `entityManager.` 
So is there any way to construct `CriteriaQuery` using `Hibernate 3.6.10` ?

I am struggling to create a query like above with `Hibernate 3.6.10.`

Answer (score 1):

With Hibernate 3.6 you cannot use JPA Criteria API.

But Hibernate had his own Criteria Query (which is deprecated in Hibernate 5):

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#querycriteria

Comment: Yes. But does hibernate's own criteria API support advance features like the ones  I have mentioned in question above ?

Comment: So then these features are obviously not available.