# jpa 2 criteria hibernate 5.2 nested joins

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, nested, criteria-api

I'm trying to add to my crud services the possibility to specify what nested relationship I need so I don't have to read everything from the database.

Take for example I have those entities

Company.java

```
private List<Department> departments;
private SalaryCode salaryCode;
```

Department.java

```
private List<Employee> employees;
private Company company;
private SalaryCode salaryCode;
```

Employee.java

```
private Department department;
private SalaryCode salaryCode
```

And my Criteria query for now is this :

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<T> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(clazz);
Root<T> root = criteriaQuery.from(clazz);

//nestedRelationships is a varargs passed as parameters
for(String nestedRelationship : nestedRelationships) {
    root.fetch(nestedRelationship, JoinType.LEFT);
}

List<T> result = session.createQuery(criteriaQuery.select(root)).list();
```

The thing is if I specify "department" as nestedRelationship and querying for Employee entity it works well but when I try to specify "department.salaryCode" it doesn't work saying " Unable to locate Attribute with the the given name ".
Of course I'm fetching "department" first and then "department.salaryCode".

Is it supported? If yes how does it work and if it's not supported what can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by making an algorithm using the Root element

```
protected void fetch(Root<T> root, String... joins) {
    //Sort the joins so they are like this :
    //A
    //A.F
    //B.E
    //B.E.D
    //B.G
    Arrays.sort(joins);

    Map<String, Fetch> flattenFetches = new HashMap<>();

    for (String join : joins) {
        try {
            if (join.contains(".")) {
                String[] subrelations = join.split("\\.");
                Fetch lastRelation = null;
                int i;

                for (i = subrelations.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    String subJoin = String.join(".", Arrays.copyOf(subrelations, i));

                    if (flattenFetches.containsKey(subJoin)) {
                        lastRelation = flattenFetches.get(subJoin);
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (lastRelation == null) {
                    lastRelation = root.fetch(subrelations[0], JoinType.LEFT);
                    flattenFetches.put(subrelations[0], lastRelation);
                    i = 1;
                }

                for (; i < subrelations.length; i++) {
                    String relation = subrelations[i];
                    String path = String.join(".", Arrays.copyOf(subrelations, i + 1));

                    if (i == subrelations.length - 1) {
                        Fetch fetch = lastRelation.fetch(relation, JoinType.LEFT);
                        flattenFetches.put(path, fetch);
                    } else {
                        lastRelation = lastRelation.fetch(relation, JoinType.LEFT);
                        flattenFetches.put(path, lastRelation);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Fetch fetch = root.fetch(join, JoinType.LEFT);
                flattenFetches.put(join, fetch);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and to use it I just have to do for example :

```
employeeController.getAll("punches", "currentSchedule.shifts", "defaultDepartment.currentSchedule.shifts",
            "defaultDepartment.company.currentSchedule.shifts", "bankExtras")
```

I would like to comment the algorithm but I do not have time and it's pretty easy to understand

Answer (score 3):

Yes,it is supported. You need to use Joins.

```
    Root<Company> root = criteriaQuery.from(Company.class);
    Join<Company,Department> joinDepartment = root.join( Company_.departments );
    Join<Department,SalaryCode> joinSalaryCode = joinDepartment.join( Department_.salaryCode );
```

To generate metamodel classes(e.g. *Department_* ) have a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3037817/1372366).