# EclipseLink: Canonical Metamodel class not found during initialization

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

In my application where I enabled logging and performance profiling, there are log entries like this for all of my entity classes:

```
[EL Finer]: metamodel: ... --Canonical Metamodel class [<class name>_] not found during initialization.
```

What does this mean?

Comment: This messages is just a warning that EclipseLink can't find the classes. The canonical model classes can be generated from JPA and used for typing in criteria queries but aren't really needed for anything else : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037593/how-to-generate-jpa-2-0-metamodel