# How to avoid hardcoding a JPA entity property name in the Sort.by(...) sorted paginated request handler?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, hardcode

I am using the an entity that has multiple properties/table columns:

```
@Entity
public class History {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    @NotNull
    @Column
    ZonedDateTime dateCreated;

    @NotNull
    @Column
    private ZonedDateTime dateValidFrom;

    ...
```

and I have a Spring MVC controller with a handler that returns such `History` entries sorted by a particular property (e.g. `dateValidFrom`). The code below is from the `HistoryService`:

```
public List<History> findAll(int page, int pageSize) {
    PageRequest pageSettings = PageRequest.of(page, pageSize, Sort.by(Sort.Direction.ASC, "dateValidFrom"));
    return historyRepo.findAll(pageSettings).stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

How can I avoid using the hardcoded `dateValidFrom` property name and have a type-safe construct (detecting renaming mistakes at compile-time)?

Comment: Pass `Sort` as a parameter?

Comment: I am assuming that I want a certain fixed (or some default sorting property). And even if I add it as a parameter, it will popup in the Controller where I will still have to hardcode it or even worse, let the user write the property name. I would like to say something like `History. ...` or somehow an enum that is bound then in the `History` entity to the properties as names.

Comment: Perhaps either something in the Criteria API (here be dragons) or Lombok's `@FieldNameConstants`.

Answer (score 1):

> JPA 2 defines a typesafe **Criteria API** which allows Criteria queries to be constructed in a strongly-typed manner, utilizing so called static `metamodel` classes. see: [JPA Static Model Generator](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/topical/html_single/metamodelgen/MetamodelGenerator.html)

These models are static classes that allows you to:
`_History.dateValidFrom`
which returns a string of the field name, thus avoiding hardcoded strings.

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60969488/2933553) for how to generate those static models: