# hibernate jpa metamodel generator: "Problem with Filer: Attempt to recreate a file for type"

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, generator, metamodel

I need to generate JPA metamodel types but I can not get rid of the mentioned filer problem. I'm using maven and have simply added this dependency in my pom.xml which triggers the annotation processor automatically:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen-jakarta</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.7.Final</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Can you post the error that you see? Try running `mvn compile -X` for details. Which Java version are you using? Did you read in the announcement that you need another dependency? https://in.relation.to/2021/06/04/hibernate-is-jakarta-jpa-2/

Comment: Thanx for your reply @ChristianBeikov. I think I found a solution myself (see below).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made some further investigations regarding the filer problem and here is what I found out (if you are in a hurry to find out about the solution of the filer problem just jump to the bottom of this answer).

Using the following dependencies in maven triggers automatic generation of jpa static metamodel when running "mvn compile":

```
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen-jakarta</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <version>5.6.12.Final</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

BTW: There's really nothing else to be done for jpa static metamodel generation.

But make sure to look at the right location for the generated code. You will find it under `target/generated-sources/annotations`.

The filer problem occurs, if you have (a copy of) jpa static metamodel source code in your "usual" source code directory, e.g. `src/main/java`. You can solve this if you delete the files in the source code directory.

If your IDE now complains about unresolvable types named *_, just add `target/generated-sources/annotations` as source code folder in the IDE's build path.

Cheers!